# Pandas to_sql gives ValueError with timezone-aware column

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I want to store a timezone-aware column in postgresql using pandas to_sql.

When the times are not timezone-aware, it works

```
times = ['201510100222', '201510110333']
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(times)
df.time.to_sql('test', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

But when I specify UTC

```
times = ['201510100222', '201510110333']
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(times, utc=True)
df.time.to_sql('test', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

I have the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot cast DatetimeIndex to dtype datetime64[us]
```

I'm using python 3.4.3, postgresql 9.4, pandas 0.17.1, sqlalchemy 1.0.5

Comment: This is not yet supported, see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9086

Comment: Thank you @joris, do you know any quick work around?

Comment: Convert your datetime column to naive datetimes and insert those?

Answer (score 8):

You have to store it as pd.Timestamp in PostgreSQL. The code below worked for me:

```
times = ['201510100222', '201510110333']
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(times, utc=True)
df['time'] = df['time'].astype(pd.Timestamp)
df.time.to_sql('test', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

But don't forget to properly create your database table with data type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE. If you are building your table directly from the to_sql command, you have to specify it explicitly:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import TIMESTAMP as typeTIMESTAMP
df.time.to_sql('test', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False,dtype=typeTIMESTAMP(timezone=True))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for pandas 1.0.3 anymore. Raises type error `TypeError: dtype '<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>' not understood
` for `df['time'] = df['time'].astype(pd.Timestamp)`.

Answer (score 5):

You can convert your datetimes to strings :

```
times = pd.DatetimeIndex(['201510100222', '201510110333'], tz="UTC")
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['time'] = [time.strftime(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z") for time in times]
```

then insert them in the database as datetimes :

```
from sqlalchemy import TIMESTAMP
df.to_sql('test', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False,
          dtype={'time': TIMESTAMP(timezone=True)})
```

It's quite an ugly solution, but on my setup, it works.

Note that postgres will display the datetimes in your current timezone. Mine is Europe/Paris, so here's what I get when I query them (psql) :

```
test=# select * from test;
          time          
------------------------
 2015-10-10 04:22:00+02
 2015-10-11 05:33:00+02
(2 rows)
```

instead of something like

```
          time          
------------------------
 2015-10-10 02:22:00+00
 2015-10-11 03:33:00+00
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with pandas 0.16.2 , so you can simply downgrade pandas to avoid the error:

```
conda remove pandas
conda install pandas=0.16.2
```

**IN THE DB:**

(1) Set timezone = 'UTC' in postgresq.conf. This makes UTC the default time zone for all connections to your DB

(2) Use timestamp with time zone (aka timestamptz) for all timestamp columns in your DB. They store values as UTC, but convert them on selection to whatever your time zone setting is.

**IN PYTHON:**

(3) always create timestamps with timezone in UTC:

```
def get_now_in_utc():
    now = datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)
    return now
```

(4) and persist them with pandas to_sql

**RESULT:**

(5) this will cause your persistence to be timezone aware and accurate.

(6) when querying from the DB (use the AT TIME ZONE expression in your query) or within the code (timezone transformations within python), you can always take the UTC time and convert it to whatever you like.

Comment: Pandas 0.16.2 does not yet support timezone aware columns, so it's not as easy as that.

Comment: @joris : (1) Set timezone = 'UTC' in postgresq.conf. This makes UTC the default time zone for all connections to your DB
(2) Use timestamp with time zone (aka timestamptz) for all timestamp columns in your DB. They store values as UTC, but convert them on selection to whatever your time zone setting is.

Answer (score 0):

I found this works for me (even allowing for tz conversion):

```
from sqlalchemy.types import TIMESTAMP as typeTIMESTAMP
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'datetime': ['2000-10-29 00:00', '2000-10-29 01:00', '2000-10-29 02:00', '2000-10-29 03:00'],
    'a': range(4),
})
df.datetime = [pd.Timestamp(i, tz='UTC').tz_convert(tz='Europe/London') for i in df.datetime]
df.datetime = df.datetime.astype(pd.Timestamp)  # needs to re-convert to Timestamp
df.to_sql(name=TEST_TABLE_NAME, con=conn, index=False, dtype={'datetime': typeTIMESTAMP(timezone=True)})

# if you want to set it as primary key
conn.execute("""ALTER TABLE "{}" ADD PRIMARY KEY (datetime);""".format(TABLE_NAME))
```